# How to replace the 'Strings' with numerical values based on a group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below table (#temp1) where I need to replace the string in the column'Formula' with the matching input 'VALUE' column based on the group 'Yearmonth'.

The 'Formula' column may be of any mathematical expression for better understanding I have mentioned a simple example below.

```
  IDNUM  formula                      INPUTNAME      VALUE    YEARMONTH
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1      imports(398)+imports(399)    imports(398)    17.000  2003:1
  2      imports(398)+imports(399)    imports(398)    56.000  2003:2
  3      imports(398)+imports(399)    imports(399)    15.000  2003:1
  4      imports(398)+imports(399)    imports(399)    126.000 2003:2
```

For eg :From the above table i need the output as

```
Idnum  Formula        Yearmonth
 1.    17.00 +15.00    2003:1
 2.    56.00 +126.00   2003:2
```

I tried with the below different query from various suggestions but coludnt achieve it. Could someone help me this out ?

Type1 :

```
SELECT
REPLACE(FORMULA, INPUTName, AttributeValue) AS realvalues, 
yearmonth 
FROM #temp1
GROUP BY yearmonth
```

TYPE2 :
USING XML PATH... In this case it got worked but I need to replace only the strings with the values and not to stuff the strings based on mathematcal operation.(Because the formula might be of any type).

```
SELECT
IDNUM = MIN(IDNUM),
FORMULA = 
    (SELECT STUFF(
        (SELECT ' +' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Value)
        FROM #temp1
        WHERE YEARMONTH = t1.YEARMONTH
        FOR XML PATH(''))
    ,1, 2, '')),
YEARMONTH
FROM #TEMP1 t1
GROUP BY YEARMONTH
```

TYPE3:Using Recursions...This is returning only the null values...

```
;with t as (
  select t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by yearmonth order by idnum) as seqnum,
         count(*) over (partition by yearmonth) as cnt
  from #temp1 t


 )

 ,cte as (
  select t.seqnum, t.yearmonth, t.cnt,
         replace(formula, inputname, AttributeValue) as formula1
  from t
  where seqnum = 1
  union all
  select cte.seqnum, cte.yearmonth, cte.cnt,
         replace(CTE.formula1, T.inputname, T.AttributeValue) as formula2
  from cte join
       t
       on cte.yearmonth = t.yearmonth 

       AND  cte.seqnum = t.seqnum + 1 
)
   select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id,formula1
   from cte
   where seqnum = cnt
```

Comment: what are those numbers `(398)`, `(399)` means? a bit unclear for me

Comment: Its just the string and the 'input name' column has the same string names... the number represents different 'ID' for the import types...

Comment: Are the expressions **always** going to follow the format `imports(X) [+imports(Y) ...]` ? If so, why not store X and Y in an additional table? Or do you need to support other sources than `imports`, or other operands than just `+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is full working example using recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [IDNUM] TINYINT
   ,[formula] VARCHAR(MAX)
   ,[INPUTNAME] VARCHAR(128)
   ,[VALUE] DECIMAL(9,3)
   ,[YEARMONTH] VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([IDNUM], [formula], [INPUTNAME], [VALUE], [YEARMONTH])
VALUES ('1', 'imports(398)+imports(399)', 'imports(398)', '17.000', '2003:1')
      ,('2', 'imports(398)+imports(399)', 'imports(398)', '56.000', '2003:2')
      ,('3', 'imports(398)+imports(399)', 'imports(399)', '15.000', '2003:1')
      ,('4', 'imports(398)+imports(399)', 'imports(399)', '126.000', '2003:2')
      ,('5', '(imports(391)+imports(392)-imports(393))/imports(394)', 'imports(391)', '5.000', '2003:3')
      ,('6', '(imports(391)+imports(392)-imports(393))/imports(394)', 'imports(392)', '10.000', '2003:3')
      ,('7', '(imports(391)+imports(392)-imports(393))/imports(394)', 'imports(393)', '3.000', '2003:3')
      ,('8', '(imports(391)+imports(392)-imports(393))/imports(394)', 'imports(394)', '-5.000', '2003:3');

WITH DataSource AS
( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YEARMONTH] ORDER BY [IDNUM]) AS [ReplacementOrderID]
          ,[YEARMONTH]
          ,[formula]
          ,[INPUTNAME] AS [ReplacementString]
          ,[VALUE] AS [ReplacementValue]
    FROM @DataSource
),
RecursiveDataSource AS
(
    SELECT [ReplacementOrderID]
          ,[YEARMONTH]
          ,REPLACE([formula], [ReplacementString], [ReplacementValue]) AS [formula]
    FROM DataSource
    WHERE [ReplacementOrderID] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
          ,DS.[YEARMONTH]
          ,REPLACE(RDS.[formula], DS.[ReplacementString], DS.[ReplacementValue]) AS [formula]
    FROM RecursiveDataSource RDS
    INNER JOIN DataSource DS
        ON RDS.[ReplacementOrderID] + 1 = DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
        AND RDS.[YEARMONTH] = DS.[YEARMONTH]
)
SELECT RDS.[YEARMONTH]
      ,RDS.[formula]
FROM RecursiveDataSource RDS
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT [YEARMONTH]
          ,MAX([ReplacementOrderID]) AS [ReplacementOrderID]
    FROM DataSource
    GROUP BY [YEARMONTH]
) DS
    ON RDS.[YEARMONTH] = DS.[YEARMONTH]
    AND RDS.[ReplacementOrderID] = DS.[ReplacementOrderID]
ORDER BY RDS.[YEARMONTH]
```

[image]

Generally, you simply want to perform multiple replacements over a string in one statement. You can have many replacement values, just play with the `MAXRECURSION` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Create sample data
DROP TABLE #temp1
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (IDNUM int, formula varchar(max), INPUTNAME varchar(max), VALUE decimal, YEARMONTH varchar(max))
INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES 
    (1, 'imports(398)+imports(399)', 'imports(398)', 17.000, '2003:1'),
    (2, 'imports(398)+imports(399)', 'imports(398)', 56.000, '2003:2'),
    (3, 'imports(398)+imports(399)', 'imports(399)', 15.000, '2003:1'),
    (4, 'imports(398)+imports(399)', 'imports(399)', 126.000, '2003:2')

--Query
;WITH t as (
    SELECT formula, YEARMONTH, IDNUM
    FROM #temp1
UNION ALL
    SELECT REPLACE(a.formula, b.INPUTNAME, CAST(b.VALUE AS varchar(100))) AS formula, a.YEARMONTH, a.IDNUM
    FROM t a
    JOIN #temp1 b ON a.YEARMONTH = b.YEARMONTH AND a.formula LIKE '%' + b.INPUTNAME + '%'
)
SELECT MIN(IDNUM) AS IDNUM, formula, YEARMONTH
FROM t
WHERE formula not LIKE '%imports(%'
GROUP BY formula, YEARMONTH
```